# What should we use for upcoming event Were to be and are to be?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Is there any meaning difference in below sentences?

What should we use to give information of future upcoming event?

(a) Elections that were to be held on Monday has been cancelled.

(b) Elections that are be be held on Monday has been cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

neither as written, use

Elections that **were** to be held on Monday *HAVE* been cancelled.

*WERE* because it now will not happen.

*HAVE* I cannot explain with a reference, sadly. It just should be so, perhaps there is a single cancellation event and that has caused this verb form to be used.

Comment: "have" because it is the present perfect. The sentence is about the current state of the elections.

Answer (score 1):

*a) Elections that were to be held on Monday have been cancelled.*

This is correct. In the past, the elections *were* to have been held. They no longer *are* to be held.

*(b) Elections that are be be held on Monday have been cancelled.*

This makes no sense. If the elections *are* to be held then they have not been cancelled. You cannot both cancel and hold the elections.